# How to declare JSON serialized type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

For example, I have some types as follow:

```js
interface A {
  id: number;
}

interface B {
  toJSON(): A;
}

interface C {
  b: B;
  c: number;
```

I want a type `JSONState<C>` which could convert the type `C` to `{ b: A, c: number }`.

I tried the following code:

```js
export type JSONState<S> = S extends { toJSON(): infer R } ? JSONState<R> : S extends (infer E)[]
  ? JSONState<E>[]
  : S extends object ? {
    [P in keyof S]?: JSONState<S[P]>
  } : S
```

But it emits the following error:

```sh
Error:(1, 13) TS2456: Type alias 'JSONState' circularly references itself.
```

What should I do?

Comment: `JSONState<C>` should convert `{ b: B, c: number }` to `{ b: A, c: number }`? Not really clear what are you trying to do

Comment: @AlekseyL. That means if a type has `toJSON` method, it should be convert to the return type of the method.

Comment: OK, I see, please update the question accordingly

Comment: There isn't any trace of JSON in this question. The function `toJSON()` incorrectly contains "JSON" in its name. [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. This means JSON a string.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) which will check if value has `toJSON` method:

```
type JSONState<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends { toJSON: () => infer J } ? J : T[P] };
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnOAEwC5kQBXAWwCNoBuLAXyy1ElkRQCFMdkwB7AFIBlAPIA5ABQBKYqjqNm4aPCTIAwt1yViHOrgTEyVWgyZgAngAcUw8ULBxIAHgAqAPmQBeTMgDaABTwQZABrCHM%20GGQXAF1iFwCY5AgAD0gQfABnH35bMWJpLw9QGGhkAWR6ZAB%20cuR4xMq6LAtrZAAxPj4vctExe0cIJzU3IA)

Comment: Well, it's OK to transform type shallowly, but what I wanted is transform the type recursively. For example: if the type `J` has `toJSON(): infer R` method too, it should be `R` rather than `J`.

Comment: Well you should write exactly what you expect to get in the question 

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved the problem with some magic thing:

````js
declare const __magicType: unique symbol;

/**
 * A magic type alias for avoiding TypeScript circle reference
 */
type JSONValue<R> = R extends { [__magicType]: infer E } ? E : R;

/**
 * Convert a type to the jsonify type of it, which means
 * it will drop the function fields and convert it to the
 * return type of its `toJSON()` if it exists.
 *
 * @example
 * ```typescript
 * interface Foo {
 *   toJSON(): number;
 * }
 *
 * interface Root {
 *   id: number;
 *   foo: Foo[];
 * }
 *
 * declare const data: JSONState<Root> // <= { id: number, foo: number[] }
 * ```
 *
 * @expermential
 */
export type JSONState<S> = JSONValue<
  S extends { toJSON(): infer R }
    ? { [__magicType]: JSONState<R> }
    : S extends object
    ? {
        [P in keyof S]: JSONState<S[P]>;
      }
    : S
>;
````

This will be easy after TypeScript v4.1 is released, you can get more information at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#recursive-conditional-types.